# Find `this` element in dynamically created rows

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to populate the textarea of the `<a class='add-product'>` clicked in the same row. Rows are created dynamically and no unique ID but all have the same class.

```
$addProduct.parents('.item-row').find("textarea[name^='item_name']").val(customers.product);
```

will populate the correct fields, but it populates all the dynamic rows with the selected results. (not populating the single row where the click event occurred)?
I have tried:

```
$(this).parents('.item-row').find("textarea[name^='item_name']").val(customers.product);
```

but `this` seems to be `null`.

My HTML:

```
  <tr class="item-row">
      <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_name[]">Hourly Rate</textarea>
      <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
      <a class="add-product" href="javascript:;" title="Add Product">A</a>
      </div></td>
      <td class="description"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_desc[]">Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs</textarea></td>
      <td><textarea class="cost" form ="testinsert" name="item_cost[]">$150.00</textarea></td>
      <td><textarea class="qty" form ="testinsert" name="item_qty[]">3</textarea></td>
      <td><span class="price" form ="testinsert" name="item_price[]">$450.00</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="item-row">
      <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_name[]">Hourly Rate</textarea>
      <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
      <a class="add-product" href="javascript:;" title="Add Product">A</a>
      </div></td>

      <td class="description"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_desc[]">Residential Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs</textarea></td>
      <td><textarea class="cost" form ="testinsert" name="item_cost[]">$95.00</textarea></td>
      <td><textarea class="qty" form ="testinsert" name="item_qty[]">3</textarea></td>
      <td><span class="price" form ="testinsert" name="item_price[]">$285.00</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="hiderow">
    <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a></td>
  </tr>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.add-product').live('click',function(){
    $("#productdiv").css("display", "block");

    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'product_fill.php',                         
        data: {action:"invoice"},                                             
        dataType: 'json',                   
        success: function(data){
            populateSelectBoxes($('#productdiv #ddproduct'), data);

            function populateSelectBoxes($select, data) {
                var products = [];
                $.each(data, function() {
                    products.push('<li data-value="'+this.autonum+'">' + this.product + '</li>');
                });
                $select.append(products.join(''));
            }

            function populateTableRow($addProduct, data, selectedCustomerAutonum) {
                var customers;
                $.each(data, function() {
                    if (this.autonum == selectedCustomerAutonum) {
                        customers = this;
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                $addProduct.parents('.item-row').find("textarea[name^='item_name']").val(customers.product);
                $addProduct.parents('.item-row').find("textarea[name^='item_desc']").val(customers.disc);
                $addProduct.parents('.item-row').find("textarea[name^='item_cost']").val(customers.rate);

            }

            $('#productdiv #ddproduct li').click(function(e) {
                var selection = $(this).attr("data-value");
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
                populateTableRow($('.add-product'), data, selection);
                $('ul').empty();
            });


        }
    });
```

select popup window:

```
<div id="productdiv">
  <form class="form" action="product_fill.php" id="contact" method="GET">
  <img src="images/button_cancel.png" class="img" id="cancel"/>
  <h2>ProductList</h2>
  <ul id="ddproduct" name="ddproductname"></ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: try `$(this).closest('.item-row').find("textarea[name='item_name']").val(customers.product);`

Comment: returns `undefined`

Comment: remove `[]` from name why do you have it?

Comment: item_name[] is an array in the name tag

Comment: Not the problem, but as a general rule `.closest()` almost always makes more sense than `.parents()`.

Comment: any idea why `this` doesn't seem to return anything ? or how I can check?

Comment: You call `populateTableRow()` with `$('.add-product')` as an argument, but that selects all of the `add-product` elements, and also you call it within the click handler of an `<li>` element - how does that `<li>` relate to the `<tr>` elements that you show?

Comment: Oh - do you want `populateTableRow()` to find the same row as was originally clicked where that click triggered the `$('.add-product').live('click',...)` handler? (That's easy enough, but it's not clear if that's what you're asking.)

Comment: @nnnnnn yes that is what I'm looking for

Comment: updated: question to show '<div>' where '<li>' are dynamically created - its further down the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you clarified that you want the `populateTableRow()` function to update elements in the same `<tr>` as has the anchor that was clicked to trigger the `$('.add-product').live('click'...` event handler.

The simplest way is just to create a variable in the scope of *that* click handler and reference it from within `populateTableRow()`:

```
$('.add-product').live('click',function(){

  var clickedRow = $(this).closest("tr");  // <--- ADD THIS PART

  $("#productdiv").css("display", "block");

  $.ajax({                                      
    url: 'product_fill.php',                         
    data: {action:"invoice"},                                             
    dataType: 'json',                   
    success: function(data){
        populateSelectBoxes($('#productdiv #ddproduct'), data);

        function populateSelectBoxes($select, data) {
            var products = [];
            $.each(data, function() {
                products.push('<li data-value="'+this.autonum+'">' + this.product + '</li>');
            });
            $select.append(products.join(''));
        }

        function populateTableRow(data, selectedCustomerAutonum) {
            var customers;
            $.each(data, function() {
                if (this.autonum == selectedCustomerAutonum) {
                    customers = this;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            clickedRow.find("textarea[name^='item_name']").val(customers.product);
            clickedRow.find("textarea[name^='item_desc']").val(customers.disc);
            clickedRow.find("textarea[name^='item_cost']").val(customers.rate);
        }

        $('#productdiv #ddproduct li').click(function(e) {
            var selection = $(this).attr("data-value");
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
            populateTableRow(data, selection);
            $('ul').empty();
        });
    }
});
```

I've removed the first argument from the `populateTableRow()` function because it's not needed.

Note also that `.live()` is really out of date (deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and *removed* in 1.9). If you are using jQuery >= 1.7 it is better to use the delegated syntax of `.on()`, or for < 1.7 but >= 1.4.2 use `.delegate()`:

```
// instead of:
$('.add-product').live('click', function() { ...

// jQuery >= 1.7:
$('#idOfYourTable').on('click', '.add-product', function() { ...

// jQuery >= 1.4.2 && < 1.7
$('#idOfYourTable').delegate('.add-product', 'click', function() { ...
```

Comment: thanks for the help, the `clickedRow` seems to work. It's populating my desc and cost, but the name is not updating. must be a typo i'm missing...

Comment: any thoughts on why: `clickedRow.find("textarea[name^='item_name'‌]").val(customers.pr‌oduct);` fails to update ?

Comment: Not sure. I can't see a typo, so I would think if it works for two of the fields it would work for all of them. Are you sure `customers.product` has a value?

Comment: The `item_name` is wrapped in an extra `<div class="delete-wpr">` with the anchor tag, could this be a problem?

Comment: That shouldn't matter with `.find()`.

Comment: resolved: I think the browser was retaining a history and after restarting session, all is working. Thanks for all your help.